# Upgraded to 12.10 from 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 12.10, launcher, panel

I upgraded to 12.10 from 12.04LTS. I can't see my Launcher. Both my Launcher and Panel look like static. How to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to upgrade from the update manager, many things could go wrong, you should have downloaded the ISO file from the website, then backup everything, then upgrade, then restore. [Check this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu).

Lets try to fix this, lets reinstall unity

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity`

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: How do I get there? I'm not an expert with Ubuntu... Total novice to be exact. Again, I can't see any of my icons... So I'm randomly clicking in areas where i remember icons being positioned.

Comment: login into virtual console by pressing (ctrl+alt+F1) while during the desktop shows no borders,icons.After logged into virtual console run the above commands.

Comment: Yea that's not working, i have no idea what the login info is. Man i feel stupid!

Comment: @user237107 you don't know what the login info are? I suggest you do a fresh installation, forget about fixing this one and reinstall the OS that you want, only this time do it right :) I did that many times myself, reinstalling a distro rather than fixing it, since you have nothing on it yet

Comment: @Fischer I know the login for the computer but as I type it in no see nothing and the response is that my information is incorrect.

Comment: @user237107 Reinstall the OS, the best solution since you have no data to lose